# Mercurial: Revert "commit action" changes

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

Suppose I have made a change to a file, `hg status` show it as modified.

Now I want to commit. Before I can do so I accidentially `hg remove` my file.
Mercurial now would remove my file on the next commit, `hg revert` would retain it from removal, my changes would be lost however.

Is exporting a patch and then importing it on top of a MQ my only option to put my file back into "modified" state?

Comment: I'm wondering how you managed to accidentally remove that file. When I try to `hg remove` a modified file, I get the following error message:

    not removing Textdokument.txt: file is modified (use -f to force removal)

TortoiseHg (under Windows) will also refuse to remove it.

Comment: please don't ask me :-) it happened with rename

Comment: @tim - `hg remove -Af filename` or `hg forget filename` (in 1.3+)

Comment: Yes, I know about the -f option, but that doesn't count as accidental, does it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about that but try adding it back with `hg add`.

And you can simply export and apply a patch without MQ.

Comment: i know, however MQ lets me manipulate my "commit" before actually doing a real commit, importing a patch always results in a commit.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Using `hg add` on a file that is scheduled to be removed from tracking will undo the remove and leave the contents untouched.

Comment: A note on your comment, Johannes Rudolph: "importing a patch always results in a commit".  You can avoid that by doing `hg import --no-commit`

Comment: im more and more realizing im a mercurial noob :-) seemed so easy in the beginning, and after thinkin about it, indeed it _is_ simple! Mercurial ftw :-)